# manipulating a JS object

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in that I need some information from an API, but am not able to dig any further, and as a result i'm only able to dig so far into the api to gather the information that i need, and it is coming as an object. Looking like this:

```
{"display_custom_hours":"Open on Oct 15 from 3:00PM - 4:00PM"}
```

However I only need this part

```
Open on Oct 15 from 3:00PM - 4:00PM
```

Am I able to use Javascript to manipulate that information to what I need?

Comment: You'd get that part with `object_name.display_custom_hours` ?

Comment: You can simply access `myObj.display_custom_hours`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already object, try this:

```
console.log(your_object.display_custom_hours);
```

If not try this:

```
var stringObj = '{"display_custom_hours":"Open on Oct 15 from 3:00PM - 4:00PM"}'; // or item received
var obj = JSON.parse(stringObj);
console.log(obj.display_custom_hours);
```

Comment: I figured out that the console wouldn't recognize 'display_custom_hours', however it was recognized if i referenced it on the front end of my code.  (very strange situation)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
var jsonData = '{"display_custom_hours":"Open on Oct 15 from 3:00PM - 4:00PM"}';
jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
alert(jsonData.display_custom_hours);
```

**Solution steps**

1. Put your data into a variable `var` , like this

   `var jsonData = '{"display_custom_hours":"Open on Oct 15 from 3:00PM - 4:00PM"}';`
2. Prase it using `JSON.parse`  function , like this

   `jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);`
3. You can use your date in this form `Object.propriety` , like this

   `alert(jsonData.display_custom_hours);`

**Output**

```
    Open on Oct 15 from 3:00PM - 4:00PM
```